# Unable to resolve module...does not exist in the haste module map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, module, haste

I am a beginner on ReactNative, I am creating a Twitter clone to practice.

I had already developed a first application and I had no problem.

But since I started the new project, after adding custom modules in the project I have this error message.

In this case I want to import a style sheet into my custom Tweet component, I added a capture, it's better for you.

[Screenshot - error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgJqV.png)

So, I followed all the instructions of the capture, except Watchmen because I'm working on Windows 10, after doing the procedure, I recreated a new project with "react-create-app", restart XDE expo and the application but the problem comes back ...

I also tried the Github procedure dealing with the problem (see the catch for the issue) here => https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to import the module, and the declaration/export of the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply follow again below steps

```
yarn add react-native-tweet-view
react-native link react-native-tweet-view
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 issue in your import :

1. You must not write the extension of the module you're importing
2. Your file is named "Tweet.style" and you try to import "Tweet.style**s**"
3. You have to import the relative path of your module

Correct import should be :

```
import styles from './Tweet.style'
```

Comment: Really sorry, I made a mistake in the post, the file is well named in Tweet.styles.js in my project

Comment: Ok, so just remove the ".js" at the end of the import.

Comment: I just tried removing the .js, the problem is still there.

Comment: Ok my bad, you have to provide a relative path ('./Tweet.style'), I'll update my answer

Comment: I added './' to the relative path and it worked, thank you very much!

By cons I often make this mistake, there is not a trick to improve this?

I think you have to have a good project structure, but which one? You do not need code in App.js, but only import custom components into App.js, is it?

Answer (score 0):

check the top of your file so that you have not imported

```
import { threadId } from 'worker_threads';
```

I removed that and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Some time this error happens because of malformed JS styles .. like

```
backgroundColor= '#fff'
```

instead of 
`backgroundColor: '#fff'` this ..